# Counting the number of occurrences of a specific exception

Tags: java

I'm dealing with a monster of a legacy application that has very bad exception handling. Specifically, all kinds of exceptions (e.g. `ClassCastException`s) are caught to be ignored somehow. Sometimes exceptions are used as control flow mechanisms.

However, we have a fairly large E2E test suite. Is it possible to somehow count the *number* of times specific exceptions are thrown throughout a test run? We're talking things like `NullPointerException`, `ClassCastException` and the like, which I'd like to get an estimation on.

Comment: Maybe print all exceptions into a log and use some unique identifier to check count from a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

As an option you probably can use java agent (as https://code.google.com/p/java-allocation-instrumenter/) to count allocations of *Exception objects.

Note. Exception may be allocated, but not thrown.

Comment: This turned out to be a dead end as I started running into impossible to solve class loader issues on JBoss.

Attaching a profiler was ultimately the way to go. The YourKit Java Profiler was - after trying out 3 others - the only one capable of aggregating exceptions, but it did so beautifully.

Now I just need to solve 200K exceptions being thrown and caught in the space of 45 min... :-/

Comment: Then why are you typing comments on StackOverflow??   LOL